# Why are these two hashes different?

Tags: cryptography, hash, openssl

openssl passwd -1 -salt 34 12 = $1$34$**jVCBepHqaSo2abdfzITRY0**

openssl passwd -1 -salt 4 123 = $1$4$**GP8wMYuBvgY93rX7yoh4Y1**

Aren't the hashes calculated with md5(password+salt)? Why are they different?

Comment: Your inputs are different, why would the hashes be the same?

Comment: @iain OP is suggesting that "12"+"34" is the same as "123"+"4" if salting meant a simple concatenation of both strings.

Comment: Not only are they different — they *should* be different. Why would you want a password verification scheme where the password of "123" and a salt of "4" is equivalent to a password of "12" and a salt of "34"? They're different inputs, so it would be a serious flaw in the algorithm if they were equivalent!

Answer (score 3):

> Aren't the hashes calculated with md5(password+salt)? ...

No they aren't. Looking at [the source code of md5crypt](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/apps/passwd.c#L317) you will see that is is way more complex. For one, it does not start with `passwd+salt` at all but starts with `passwd$1$salt` and then feeds another md5 based on passwd and salt into this hash etc. Thus very different and more complex than your assumption, whatever this assumption was based on.

See also https://pthree.org/2015/08/07/md5crypt-explained/ for a more detailed description of the algorithm including python code.

Answer (score 2):

Openssl's MD5-based password is not just `md5(pw + salt)`.  It's md5crypt which is keystrengthened 1000 times by calculating a hash and then alternating appending the salt or password to the hash of the last step.

See for example:

https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=32